# to use [self presentModalViewController: animated:] and black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I create one program that show list of book from url in tableview (any book has many images)
I want when to click any cell to go in next page (next page is UIScroll that show images) and show images of that book
I have one problem that it is when to click any cell and when go next page show black screen instead UIScrollView include many images.

this is my code :
**RecipeViewController.h**

```
#import "RecipeViewController.h"

@interface RecipeViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@end
```

**RecipeViewController.m**

```
#import "RecipeViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RecipeViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *recipes;
    NSInteger num;
}
@synthesize table;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Recipe Book";
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

    NSString *numberbook = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/book.php?all"]];

    NSInteger numbook = [numberbook integerValue];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numbook; i++)
    {
        Recipe *si = [Recipe new];
        //NSLog(@"%d,%@",i,si);

        NSString *c = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/book.php?info=1&b=%d",i]]];        
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/book.php?p=1&b=%d",i]]];
        si.name = [NSString stringWithString:c];
        si.imageFile = data;

        if(!recipes){
            recipes = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [recipes addObject:si];
    }
    num = numbook;

    // Remove table cell separator
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    // Assign our own backgroud for the view
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"common_bg"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add padding to the top of the table view
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return recipes.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Display recipe in the table cell
    Recipe *recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:recipe.imageFile];

    UILabel *recipeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    recipeNameLabel.text = recipe.name;

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *obj = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    int x = (indexPath.row)+1;
    NSLog(@"x : %d",x);
    obj.yourValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(indexPath.row)+1];
    NSLog(@"yourValue1 : %@",obj.yourValue);
    obj.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
@end
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "RecipeViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView *scroller;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Recipe *rec;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *yourValue;
@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize scroller,yourValue;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int m1 = [self.yourValue integerValue];
   NSLog(@"M1 : %d",m1);

    NSString *bookID = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/book.php?info=0&b=%d",m1]]];

    NSInteger num1 = [bookID integerValue]; 
    NSLog(@"%d",num1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
    {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.100/mamal/book.php?p=%d&b=%d",i,m1];
        NSData *dat = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];
        NSLog(@"%@",s);
        UIImageView *imagen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dat]];
        imagen.frame = CGRectMake((i-1)*320, 0, 320, 460);
        [scroller addSubview:imagen];
    }
    scroller.delegate = self;
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*num1, 460);
    scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;  
}

@end
```

Comment: Where does DetailViewController's view come from? Ae you making this controller in a xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call:
`[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];` rather than just `[[DetailViewController alloc]init];`  as at this point, it doesn't have an Xib to inflate (unless you overrode the init method)

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem, if you are using StoryBoard you have to init the view controller this way:

```
UIStoryboard *storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

                storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                YourViewController *newVC =[storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCId"];
```

You have to put your identifier in the storyboard, selecting the view you want to show and then selecting the identity inspector, there you have the option to write the id that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You not at all calling DetailViewController How it shows the image .Try this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: may help you

```
DetailViewController *DVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];
```